# How to remove and animation on menu for a Wordpress website using Divi theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, css, animation

See the top menu here:  http://larouchemc.com/demo/qweb/fr/evenements/

There is an animation on page load (menu slides from left to right) that I want to remove. But I can't see if it's jQuery or CSS3 animation. I would like to know how to disable it. I can't find any parameters in the Divi theme options.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's jQuery that's doing it.  It's possible it could be in your settings to turn it off.  If you didn't want't to touch the jQuery though, it looks like you could use CSS to force it's placement for a specific range:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 981px) {
     padding-left: 135px !important;
     -moz-transition: none;
     -webkit-transition: none;
     transition: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

@rmh Your CSS isn't targetting any CSS selector and that can be removed simply by using this CSS.

```
.mobile_nav.opened .et_mobile_menu {
display: block !important;}
```